# Disable Fullcalendar-scheduler event snapping while dragging

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

is it possible to disable rowsnapping while dragging in [Fullcalendar-scheduler](http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/)? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation and the code didn't show any signs of it being an option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by overwriting the renderDrag function in the prototype chain like so:

```
$.fullCalendar.views.timeline.class.prototype.renderDrag = function() {
    return false;
}
```

this way the draghelper will never be rendered in timeline subviews (day, week, month).